# Faster search in INTARRAY column

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I have table with approximately 300 000 rows with `INT[]` column type

Each array contains approximately  2000 elements

I created index for this array column

`create index index_name ON table_name USING GIN (column_name)`

Then run query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM table_name 
WHERE
column_name@> ARRAY[1777]
```

This query runs very slow `Execution time: 66886.132 ms` and as `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` shows, not uses `GIN` index, only `Seq Scan` index is used.

Why not uses Postgres GIN index and main destination: how to run above query as fast, as it is possible?

**EDIT**

This is result from `explain (analyze, verbose)` for above query

```
Aggregate  (cost=10000024724.75..10000024724.76 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=61087.513..61087.513 rows=1 loops=1)
  Output: count(*)
  ->  Seq Scan on public.users  (cost=10000000000.00..10000024724.00 rows=300 width=0) (actual time=12104.651..61087.500 rows=5 loops=1)
        Output: id, email, pass, nick, reg_dt, reg_ip, gender, curr_location, about, followed_tag_ids, avatar_img_ext, rep_tag_ids, rep_tag_id_scores, stats, status
        Filter: (users.rep_tag_ids @> '{1777}'::integer[])
        Rows Removed by Filter: 299995
Planning time: 0.110 ms
Execution time: 61087.564 ms
```

This is table and index definitions

```
CREATE TABLE users
(
  id serial PRIMARY KEY,
  rep_tag_ids integer[] DEFAULT '{}'
  -- other columns here
);

create index users_rep_tag_ids_idx ON users USING GIN (rep_tag_ids);
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add the **complete** execution plan (from  `explain (analyze, verbose)`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Ok, just a moment

Comment: Provide table and index definitions.

Comment: @Jakub Kania please see, I added definitions in question

Comment: First, run `ANALYZE table_name`. Then, for debugging, try to `SET enable_seqscan=off` and _in the same session_ rerun `EXPLAIN ANALYZE....`. What does it say now?

Comment: @Ctx I already tried `SET enable_seqscan=off` but `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`gives same, what i showed in question

Comment: are you sure you created index and run this query for the same schema and table? index should be hit

Comment: @Dmitry I have only one `public` shema

Comment: @OTARIKI I indeed suspected this, since the cost for the seqscan was so high. However, there must be fundamental reasons, why the index is not used, then. Usually this means, that the index is not appropriate for the query, but from your description it seems ok. To analyze this further, you would probably have to create a minimal table, which still has this issue, dump it and provide it for download.

Comment: The estimates and actuals are really way off. Did `public.users` change anything?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should help query optimizer to use index. Install [intarray](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/intarray.html) extension for PostgreSQL if you don't have it yet and then recreate your index using gin__int_ops operator class.

```sql
DROP INDEX users_rep_tag_ids_idx;
CREATE INDEX users_rep_tag_ids_idx ON users USING gin (rep_tag_ids gin__int_ops);
```

Comment: I have installed intarray extension, but wow, `gin__int_ops` what a magic word ! index was used and now, `Execution time: 1077.352 ms`. Thank you so much!

Comment: @OTARIKI It's not a magic word, it's in the documentation that GIST gets it by default by GIN doesn't. That's the reason why I asked you for definitions.